# Background Img (local file) will not display

Tags: css, background

I am trying to set the background image with a local file however, my code does not appear to be working. Can anyone tell me how to correct this issue? Below is my code, there is also an img link that will show you my file directory.

```
  body {

   background: url('../public/images/backgroundImg.JPG');
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: scroll;
   }
```

[code link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WozvI.png)

Comment: Are you missing the `pics` directory (between images and backgroundImg.JPG)?

Comment: What is the code link supposed to show?

Answer (score 0):

The filepath is wrong, according to your posted image it should also contain a `pics` folder:

```
background: url('../public/images/pics/backgroundImg.JPG');
```